# What updates `/var/log/btmp`? How to stop it?

Tags: ssh, logging, authentication, login

*Before providing an answer, please read the question till then end. ESPECIALLY THE SECTION on "Solutions" I am not looking for!*

I have a server which runs SSH on a public IP address. Unsurprisingly, I see a lot of failed login attempts which get logged in `/var/log/btmp`. What part of the system does log those message and how do I stop it? Does sshd updates `btmp` itself or is it a PAM module?

I found the option `nowtmp` for `pam_lastlog` in the man pages which disables logging to `wtmp` and I wonder whether this disables `btmp`, too, even though the man page doesn't say so.

My `sshd_config` is:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server
HostbasedAuthentication       no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication  no
PasswordAuthentication        no
PubkeyAuthentication          yes
PermitRootLogin               no
LogLevel ERROR
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LANGUAGE LC_ADDRESS LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_NAME LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE
AcceptEnv COLORTERM
```

Enabling PAM is my distros default and I want to keep it as there are several PAM module which do relevant stuff during login (pam_systemd and pam_limits to enforce certain user limits).

The list of used PAM modules:

```
server ~ # cat /etc/pam.d/* | egrep -o -e 'pam_.*\.so' | sort | uniq
pam_access.so
pam_cap.so
pam_deny.so
pam_env.so
pam_faillock.so
pam_lastlog.so
pam_limits.so
pam_loginuid.so
pam_mail.so
pam_motd.so
pam_nologin.so
pam_passwdqc.so
pam_permit.so
pam_rootok.so
pam_shells.so
pam_systemd.so
pam_time.so
pam_unix.so
pam_wheel.so
pam_xauth.so
```

Moreover, I found this snippet in `/etc/login.defs` while I was grepping for `[uwb]tmp` in `/etc`:

```
#
# Enable logging and display of /var/log/lastlog login(1) time info.
#
# NOTE: This setting should be configured via /etc/pam.d/ and not in this file.
#LASTLOG_ENAB           yes

#
# If defined, login(1) failures will be logged here in a utmp format.
# last(1), when invoked as lastb(1), will read /var/log/btmp, so...
#
# NOTE: This setting should be configured via /etc/pam.d/ and not in this file.
#FTMP_FILE      /var/log/btmp
```

Obviously, the configuration directives are *not* defined, but commented out. Unfortunately, the comment does not state which PAM module should be configured instead.

"Solutions" I am not looking for:

- Install logrotate and rotating "away" `btmp` on a regular basis
- Use a cron job or alike to remove or clear `btmp` on a regular basis with something like `echo -n > /var/log/btmp`
- Use fail2ban or other tools to temporarily block those IPs to reduce the amount of failed attempts and hence the amount of of log data
- Move SSH to another port for the same reason as in the previous point
- Restrict the allowed source IPs via iptables (as I don't use a fixed source IP)
- Disabling PAM completely (as certain modules are required)
- Any other work arounds

I am looking for a real solution which simply stops logging failed attempts in the first place. If possible, I would like to keep the record of successful past and current logins in `/var/log/lastlog`,  `/var/log/utmp` and `/var/log/wtmp`, but this is not a must.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (easiest) would be to do the following:

1. rm -r /var/log/btmp*
2. Again ensure that there is nothing referencing /var/log/btmp in the /etc/logrotate.conf or any configuration file under /etc/logrotate.d
3. ln -s /dev/null /var/log/btmp

---

If you wish to go further down into the system, from what I could determine from a web search, systemd is responsible.  There is a configuration file that you MIGHT (I make no guarantees,warrenties,use at your own risk,etc.) be able to change to prevent creation of this file.

1. rm -f /var/log/btmp*
2. Again ensure that there is nothing referencing /var/log/btmp in the /etc/logrotate.conf or any configuration file under /etc/logrotate.d
3. Edit file /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf to remove the creation of /var/log/btmp.
4. verify that /var/log/btmp* is not present
   5.reboot to verify change

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I conjuncture that what I want to do is simply not possible. The logs are created by OpenSSH itself and there seems to be no configuration option to disable that behaviour.

I had a look at the source code of OpenSSH 9.5.

File `configure.ac` checks whether OpenSSH is being compiled for Linux via `case $host`. The case `*-*-linux*` defines the C macro `USE_BTMP`.

If the C macro `USE_BTMP` is set, the file `defines.h` defines the C macro `CUSTOM_FAILED_LOGIN`.

In file `auth2.c` the function `userauth_finish` always calls the function `auth_log` unconditionally.

In file `auth.c` the function `auth_log` always calls the function `record_failed_login` for failed attempts. The function call is guarded by the C macro `CUSTOM_FAILED_LOGIN`, but this is defined (see above). This function call is compiled into Linux builds. Besides `CUSTOM_FAILED_LOGIN` there is no other condition. In particular, there does not seem to be any dependency on any configuration which could be set at runtime.

Ultimately, in file `loginrec.c` the function `record_failed_login` updates `btmp`.

Maybe I missed something, but it seems that failed attempts are always log to `btmp` for Linux builds of OpenSSH.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you - only `shadow` honors the setting in `/etc/login.defs`, and OpenSSH does not and will write to `/var/log/btmp` regardless. Seems like hacky workarounds are the only way to disable `btmp` :/